# Why in this case the Treenode I try to delete is not deleted?

Tags: c++

I wrote a function to delete a node with its value equals given key in a BST, I tried a simple example [5,3,6], and delete key = 3. But when I ran this code, 3 is not deleted.The output of this code: 
root = 5 left = 3 right = 6
Why? Thanks!

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};

// delete key in the tree
TreeNode* deleteNode(TreeNode* root, int key) {
    TreeNode* cur = root;
    // find the node to delete
    while(cur) {
        if(cur->val == key) break;
        if(cur->val > key) cur = cur->left;
        else cur = cur->right;
    }
    if(!cur) return root;
    // I want to delete the node of val 3 here
    // here cur == root->left, I though when I do cur = 0, root->left will also be set to 0
    if(!cur->left && !cur->right) {
        assert(cur == root->left);
        delete cur;
        cur = 0;
    }
    if(root) cout << "root = " << root->val << endl;
    // but root->left is not nullptr when I ran this, and 3 still exists
    if(root->left) cout << "left = " << root->left->val << endl;
    if(root->right) cout << "right = " << root->right->val << endl;
    return root;
}

int main() {
    TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(5);
    TreeNode* l = new TreeNode(3);
    TreeNode* r = new TreeNode(6);
    root->left = l;
    root->right = r;
    deleteNode(root, 3);
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example run of your code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a dangling pointer. You need to set `left` in the "parent" node to `NULL`. Similarly, if you delete a node on the right, you need to set the parent's `right` pointer to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

`root->left` is not a null pointer because you never set it to NULL. You set `cur` to NULL. AS such, you go on to dereference a deleted pointer, which is undefined behavior. In your case, the memory previously allocated for the left node has remain unchanged and appears to still be there when you query it.